# what does interference between two decays amplitudes mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

can anyone explain to me what does interference between two decay amplitudes mean?
I'm reading about the GLW and ADS methods used to extract the CKM angle gamma they are both based on the interference between two B->DK decay amplitudes

Comment: Do you know what interference between two amplitudes means in plain ol' quantum mechanics? In other contexts in field theory?

Comment: no i would appreciate it if you could explain it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sorts of decays can proceed via two routes to go from the B to the final-state hadrons (pions & kaons). For example (ADS method),

$B^-\to D^0K^-\to K^+\pi^- K^-$

$B^-\to \bar{D}^0K^-\to K^+\pi^- K^-$

The amplitudes of both of these routes will contribute to the final state with different phases, hence 'interference'.

This is summarised nicely on the following slide:

[image: Slide from talk at LHCb-UK 2015]